# In Blender, how do I programmatically display a viewport rendering in a window just like if you pressed F12?

Tags: python, blender

I know I can call `bpy.ops.render.opengl()` and that will create the render, but what I want to do is to create and then view the render, just like what happens when you use the **View > Viewport Render Image** menu item. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: As a comment, since it [certainly looks like all the menu item does is call that API](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/release/scripts/startup/bl_ui/space_view3d.py#L1132), it's weird that it'd act differently from the console...

Comment: Yep, it creates the render, but doesn't display it. I can use the Rendering Room to display it, but just wanted to see it in a window.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you are looking for is:

```
bpy.ops.render.opengl('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

It will display the render on a new window.